# Navigation component crash on rotate

Tags: android, kotlin, android-architecture-navigation

Navigation component crash on the device rotate

```
2019-04-15 11:50:08.589 21493-21493/me.rankov.kaboom E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: me.rankov.kaboom, PID: 21493
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: navigation destination me.rankov.kaboom:id/actionHomeToCountry is unknown to this NavController
        at androidx.navigation.NavController.navigate(NavController.java:803)
        at androidx.navigation.NavController.navigate(NavController.java:744)
        at androidx.navigation.NavController.navigate(NavController.java:730)
        at androidx.navigation.NavController.navigate(NavController.java:718)
        at me.rankov.kaboom.login.LoginActivity.navigateToRegister(LoginActivity.kt:22)
        at me.rankov.kaboom.login.LoginPresenterImpl.checkRegistration(LoginPresenterImpl.kt:49)
        at me.rankov.kaboom.login.LoginPresenterImpl.onStart(LoginPresenterImpl.kt:37)
        at me.rankov.kaboom.login.LoginActivity.onStart(LoginActivity.kt:45)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1392)
        at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:7231)
```

It crash here

```
override fun navigateToRegister(fragmentId: Int, bundle: Bundle) {
    findNavController(R.id.login_host_fragment).navigate(fragmentId, bundle)
}
```

I call it from presenter with onStart event

```
val nickname = loginInteractor.getNickname()
val country = loginInteractor.getCountry()
when {
    nickname.isEmpty() -> {
        val bundle = bundleOf("user" to user)
        loginView?.navigateToRegister(R.id.actionHomeToName, bundle)
    }
    country < 0 -> loginView?.navigateToRegister(R.id.actionHomeToCountry)
    else -> loginView?.navigateToMain()
}
```

The full code is here: [login activity](https://gist.github.com/beersheba/4df8dc9cab340180b13ce1beee48ead9) and [presenter](https://gist.github.com/beersheba/596cf11acd68122f2d4a3dacaf1372d8)

Here is my host fragment:

```
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/login_host_fragment"
    android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
    android:layout_width="395dp"
    android:layout_height="322dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    app:defaultNavHost="true"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:navGraph="@navigation/login" />
```

Here is the [navigation graph](https://gist.github.com/beersheba/8c7bede3461c2ec6a49de483fc2a74d4).

Without orientation change it works as expected.

Comment: When are you calling the 'navigateToRegister` function?

Comment: @LucaNicoletti this is how i switch navigation fragments from my presenter

Comment: please shpw navigation graph as well

Comment: @AndreyRankov I know what that function does, I need to know from **WHERE** it is called

Comment: @JohnJoe please check, I added code and nav graph

Comment: your app crashed when it comes to this line ? `country < 0 -> loginView?.navigateToRegister(R.id.actionHomeToCountry)`

Comment: @JohnJoe crash on any navigateToRegister method. but after screen rotate. before it works

Comment: You should have another `navigateToRegister` method with only one parameter, right ?

Comment: @JohnJoe yes. look at the full presenter code i added

Comment: at where you rotate? Is it in `loginNameFragment` ?

Comment: @JohnJoe yes. it's `LoginNameFragment` or `LoginCountryFragment`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191900/discussion-between-john-joe-and-andrey-rankov).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because you did not specify the action on `LoginNameFragment`.

```
<fragment
        android:id="@+id/loginNameFragment"
        android:name="me.rankov.kaboom.login.LoginNameFragment"
        android:label="fragment_login_name"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_login_name">
        <action
            android:id="@+id/actionNameToCountry"
            app:destination="@+id/loginCountryFragment"
            app:enterAnim="@anim/slide_in_right"
            app:exitAnim="@anim/slide_out_left"
            app:popUpTo="@+id/login_nav"
            app:popUpToInclusive="true" />

        <action   
           android:id="@+id/actionHomeToCountry" 
           app:destination="@+id/loginCountryFragment" 
           app:enterAnim="@anim/slide_in_right" 
           app:exitAnim="@anim/slide_out_left" 
           app:popUpTo="@+id/login_nav" 
           app:popUpToInclusive="true" />

 </fragment>
```

Comment: Can you explain with more details? I have the same problem. Shoud I add every action to all fragments?

Comment: @Davide if you need to open a a new fragment B from fragment A, then you need to specific the action in fragment A.

Comment: Thanks.. I found my problem, it's more design problem. I call navigate from activity. I'm refactoring the code where switch to fragments are made into the activity ( replace of fm )

Answer (score 6):

There is a problem with nav controller backstack after changed config

In your Activity with fragment: try saving the nav controller state before changing the configuration. After changing the configuration, add it back to the nav controller again. Like:

```
override fun onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState: Bundle) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState)
    savedInstanceState.putBundle("nav_state", fragment.findNavController().saveState())
}
override fun onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState: Bundle) {
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState)
    fragment.findNavController().restoreState(savedInstanceState.getBundle("nav_state"))
}
```

That was my case

Comment: Do we have any other solution? this is giving `TransactionTooLargeException` with app crashing in some devices.

Answer (score 0):

use these dependency version

```
implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:2.3.0-alpha04"
implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:2.3.0-alpha04"
```